# Find a formula for $a_n$ that satisfies $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n} = 2 \sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ if $ n > 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

$a_{n} = 1 \ \ when \ \ n = 0 , and \ \ a_{n} =  2 \sqrt{a_{n-1}} \ \  when \ \ n > 0$

I'm a complete beginner at solving something like this, and I'm not sure where to start. The two methods I know are iterative expansion which I have trouble understanding how it works. And I know how to use induction, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Now just by doing a few terms by hand (hopefully correctly) here's what I got,

$ 1, 2, 2\sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}$ and I'm pretty sure it just has n amount of $2\sqrt{2}$ under the sqrt sign.

I'm not sure how to progress with these types of problems in general. Thanks.

Comment: Notice $2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}} = 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}=2\cdot2^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot2^{\frac{1}{4}}=2^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{...}}}$$
$$=2^{(1+\frac12+\frac14+...+\frac1{2^{n-1}})}$$
$$=2^{\bigg(\frac{1-\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}\bigg)}$$
$$=2^{2(1-\frac1{2^{n}})}$$
$$=4^{(1-\frac1{2^{n}})}$$

Comment: How did you get to step 3?

Comment: The sum $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. It is a geometric series with $a=1$ and $r=\frac12$ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series.

Comment: So you found the summation of the series in the exponent?

Comment: Yes the summation $1+\frac12+\frac14+...+\frac1{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1-\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}$

Answer (score 3):

Divide it by 4 and we get $${a_n\over 4} =\sqrt{a_{n-1}\over 4}$$

Let $b_n = a_n/4$ then we have $$b_n = \sqrt{b_{n-1}}$$ $$=\sqrt[2^2]{b_{n-2}}$$

$$=\sqrt[2^3]{b_{n-3}}$$
$$=\sqrt[2^4]{b_{n-4}}$$
$$\vdots $$
$$=\sqrt[2^n]{b_{0}}$$

Since $b_0= a_0/4 = 1/4$ we have $$a_n = 4\cdot \sqrt[2^n]{{1\over 4}}$$

Comment: Hi! So this is starting to make some sense to me. Could you explain a few things though? At the start when you divide by 4, should there be a 1/2 left on the outside for the RHS? When you set $b_n$ to $a_n$/4 I'm having trouble following you equations, shouldn't the RHS be over 4 inside the square root like the top equation?

Comment: As they set $b_n=\frac{a_n}{4}$ the term $b_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{4}$ as well. This allows them to proceed to write $b_n=\sqrt{b_{n-1}}$ and then repeatedly apply this formula to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You've found the sequence begins $2^0,\,2^1,\,2^{3/2},\,2^{7/4}$. You may prove by induction that $a_n=2^{2-2^{1-n}}$. (It helps to first define $b_n:=\log_2 a_n$ so $b_0=0,\,b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{2}+1$, implying $b_n$ differs from the fixed point $2$ of $x\mapsto\frac{x}{2}+1$ by a geometric sequence.)